# Using your own dataset with tfds.load in google

Tags: python, tensorflow, image-processing, keras, google-colaboratory

I'm trying to creating an image classifier, but instead of using one of those datasets that TensorFlow already has ('beans' in this case), I want to use my own dataset.

For reference, this is called 'flower-detection' and the images are split into 'training' and testing'. I've already uploaded it into Google Drive and mounted it, but I don't know how to use it in tfds.load. I'm following a tutorial, so is there a way that I can change this line of code below to use my own dataset?

```
ds_test = tfds.load(name="beans", split="test")
```

How would I get the dataset from Google Drive into tfds.load? And do I put in the complete folder that says 'flower-detection' for name, or do I put 'flower-detection/training' and 'flower-detection/testing', respectively?

Answer (score 0):

As per [the Tensorflow docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds), tfds provides ready to use datasets. This means, there isn't any provision to upload your own and use it.

But, it is not the end of the road, you can follow this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification) from tensorflow. I will outline the important code that you will have to use to create the dataset.

```
train_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  subset="training",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)

val_ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.image_dataset_from_directory(
  data_dir,
  subset="validation",
  seed=123,
  image_size=(img_height, img_width),
  batch_size=batch_size)
```

Here use data_dir according to your training and testing path.

Then you can use it to train the model.

```
history = model.fit(
  train_ds,
  validation_data=val_ds,
  epochs=epochs
)
```

Comment: As I wrote in my answer data_dir should be the path of your training and testing files.