# Error while using VGG16 pretrained model for grayscale images

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, vgg-net

I am working on sign language detection using VGG16 pre-trained model with grayscale images. When I am trying to run the model.fit command, I am getting the following error.

**CLARIFICATION**

I already have images as RGB form but I want to use them as grayscale to check if they would work with grayscale. The reason being, with color images, I am not getting the accuracy which I am expecting. It is having test accuracy of max 40% only and getting overfitted on dataset.

[image: Error message]

Also, this is my model command

`vgg = VGG16(input_shape= [128, 128] + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)`

This is my model.fit command

```
history = model.fit(
  train_x,
  train_y,
  epochs=15,
  validation_data=(test_x, test_y),
  callbacks=[early_stop, checkpoint],
  batch_size=32,shuffle=True)
```

I am new to working with pre-trained models. When I am trying to run the code with color images with 3 channels, my model is getting into overfitting and val_accuracy doesn't rise above 40% so I want to give try the grayscale images as I have added many data augmentation techniques but accuracy is not improving. Any leads are welcomed as I am stuck into this for long time now.

Comment: If you are using grayscale then the position must be like this [130,130,1] not like [130,130,3] because there is only 1 colour channel in grayscale images.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. Right now I have color images but I want to use them as grayscale. That is my question.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest (and likely fastest) solution I can think of is to just convert your image to rgb. You can do this as part of your model.

```py
model = Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb),
  vgg
])
```

This will fix your issue with VGG. I also see that you're missing the last dimensionality for your images. Images in grayscale are expected to be of shape `[height, width, 1]`, but you simply have `[height, width]`. You can fix this using `tf.expand_dims`:

```py
model = Sequential([
  tf.keras.layers.Lambda(
    lambda x: tf.image.grayscale_to_rgb(tf.expand_dims(x, -1))
  ),
  vgg,
])
```

Note that this solution solves the problem *in the graph*, so it runs online. Meaning, at runtime, you can feed data exactly the same way you have it now (in the shape `[128, 128]`, without a channels dimension) and it will still functionally work. If this is your expected dimensionality during runtime, this will be faster than manipulating your data before throwing it into the model.

By the way, none of this is ideal, given that VGG was trained specifically to work best with color images. Just thought I should add that.

Comment: I already have images as rgb only with 3 channels, but I want to use them as grayscale.

Comment: @NinadKulkarni your error message would like to argue otherwise. You're passing in a grayscale image.

Comment: Yes, becoz I want to pass it as grayscale and that is why this error is coming.

Comment: @NinadKulkarni have you looked at the answers provided to you on this post? Either of them would help you handle exactly what you are encountering

Comment: Yes, I am trying that only which are suggested. Would get back if something I am stuck it.

Answer (score 1):

**Why are you getting overfitting?**

Maybe for different reasons:

1. Your images and labels don't equally exist in the train, Val, test. (maybe you have images in train and don't have them in test.) Or your train, Val, test data don't stratify correctly and you train your model on a specific area in your data and features.
2. You Dataset is very small and you need more data.
3. Maybe you have noise in your datase, first make sure to remove noise from the dataset. (if you have noise, model fit on your noise.)

**How can you input grayscale images to `VGG16`?**

For Using `VGG16`, you need to input 3 channels images. For this reason, you need to concatenate your images like below to get three channels images from grayscale:

```
image = tf.concat([image, image, image], -1)
```

**Example of training `VGG16` on grayscale images from `fashion_mnist` dataset:**

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

train, val, test = tfds.load(
    'fashion_mnist',
    shuffle_files=True, 
    as_supervised=True, 
    split = ['train[:85%]', 'train[85%:]', 'test']
)

def resize_preprocess(image, label):
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (32, 32))
    image = tf.concat([image, image, image], -1)
    image = tf.keras.applications.densenet.preprocess_input(image)
    return image, label
    

train = train.map(resize_preprocess, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test  = test.map(resize_preprocess, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val   = val.map(resize_preprocess, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


train = train.repeat(15).batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
test = test.batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val  = val.batch(64).prefetch(tf.data.AUTOTUNE)


base_model = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False, input_shape=(32,32,3))
base_model.trainable = False ## Not trainable weights


model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(base_model)
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.4))    
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=.4))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))        
model.compile(loss = tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=False),
              optimizer='Adam', 
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()

fit_callbacks = [tf.keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_accuracy', patience = 4, restore_best_weights = True)]

history = model.fit(train, steps_per_epoch=150, epochs=5, batch_size=64, validation_data=val, callbacks=fit_callbacks)
model.evaluate(test)
```

Output:

```
Model: "sequential_17"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 vgg16 (Functional)          (None, 1, 1, 512)         14714688  
                                                                 
 flatten_3 (Flatten)         (None, 512)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_9 (Dense)             (None, 1024)              525312    
                                                                 
 dropout_6 (Dropout)         (None, 1024)              0         
                                                                 
 dense_10 (Dense)            (None, 256)               262400    
                                                                 
 dropout_7 (Dropout)         (None, 256)               0         
                                                                 
 dense_11 (Dense)            (None, 10)                2570      
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 15,504,970
Trainable params: 790,282
Non-trainable params: 14,714,688
_________________________________________________________________
Epoch 1/5
150/150 [==============================] - 6s 35ms/step - loss: 0.8056 - accuracy: 0.7217 - val_loss: 0.5433 - val_accuracy: 0.7967
Epoch 2/5
150/150 [==============================] - 4s 26ms/step - loss: 0.5560 - accuracy: 0.7965 - val_loss: 0.4772 - val_accuracy: 0.8224
Epoch 3/5
150/150 [==============================] - 4s 26ms/step - loss: 0.5287 - accuracy: 0.8080 - val_loss: 0.4698 - val_accuracy: 0.8234
Epoch 4/5
150/150 [==============================] - 5s 32ms/step - loss: 0.5012 - accuracy: 0.8149 - val_loss: 0.4334 - val_accuracy: 0.8329
Epoch 5/5
150/150 [==============================] - 4s 25ms/step - loss: 0.4791 - accuracy: 0.8315 - val_loss: 0.4312 - val_accuracy: 0.8398
157/157 [==============================] - 2s 15ms/step - loss: 0.4457 - accuracy: 0.8325
[0.44566288590431213, 0.8324999809265137]
```

Comment: can you just guide me on how I can split the image dataset into train test using your example of mnist?

Comment: @NinadKulkarni, In this line `train, val, test = tfds.load('fashion_mnist', shuffle_files=True, as_supervised=True, split = ['train[:85%]', 'train[85%:]', 'test'])` came from `fashion_mnist` dataset and trian and test have 50000, 10000 images, but we specify 15% of train images split to val and 85% to train. Maybe this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets/api_docs/python/tfds/load) helps you.

Comment: just a little doubt. In the link you shared, there is one parameter of ```data_dir=``` . So, can I provide the path to my dataset there to use it on my dataset?

Comment: @NinadKulkarni, If I understand correctly, you need [tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/image_dataset_from_directory) for reading your own image from specific directory

Comment: So is it possible that I can use that with ```tfds.load()``` ?

Comment: @NinadKulkarni, No, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65726406/1740577)